# Erratic 'connection refused'

Tags: server, smtp

I am unable to send emails from `smtp-mail.outlook.com`

`ufw` and antivirus are disabled:

```
Sending of the message failed.
The message could not be sent because connecting to Outgoing server (SMTP) smtp-mail.outlook.com failed. The server may be unavailable or is refusing SMTP connections. Please verify that your Outgoing server (SMTP) settings are correct and try again.
```

This error is present only on Linux based machines, Windows and Mac no present errors:

```
telnet smtp-mail.outlook.com 587
Trying 98.124.245.24...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Also:

```
telnet smtp-mail.outlook.com 25
Trying 98.124.245.24...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

And `ping 98.124.245.24` works

What could be the problem?

Comment: yes ping works just fine. I temporarily removed 'mail' and works OK. After a couple of months smtp-mail.outlook.com 587 started working again and I restored 'mail'.

Answer (score 1):

The resolved address seems to be the issue, `98.124.245.24` is not working for me as well. However `telnet 40.100.29.34 587` works fine. `40.100.29.34` is the ip-address resolution for `smtp-mail.outlook.com` on my machine. You should check the resolved ip of server on Mac as well.

Comment: the irony is mine sometime works normal like many years before but this issue just started 4-5 days ago. Randomly sometimes works on both Linux machines but can't figure out.